# GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, exception, compiler-flags

I have a pure Objective-C project (no C++ anywhere). Can I turn off GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS or do Objective-C exceptions rely on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using any C++ code, you can turn it off (it only applies to C++ code). Or you can leave it on -- it won't really matter either way.